# drag a div within div

Tags: jquery, drag

I am using "easyui" jquery to drag div, but problem is that div drag within whole body not with in parent div.

code:

```
$('#dd2').draggable();
$('#dd3').draggable();
$('#dd4').draggable();
```

Comment: I know you can do this with the Jquery ui library, http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: You forgot the end, Help me _superman_ . . .

Comment: "help me" help you, read the doc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi friends i got the solution, add some code in your script

```
  <script>
function constrain(e){
    var d = e.data;
    if (d.left < 0){d.left = 0}
    if (d.top < 0){d.top = 0}
    if (d.left + $(d.target).outerWidth() > $(d.parent).width()){
        d.left = $(d.parent).width() - $(d.target).outerWidth();
    }
    if (d.top + $(d.target).outerHeight() > $(d.parent).height()){
        d.top = $(d.parent).height() - $(d.target).outerHeight();
    }
}
</script>
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #ccc;width:400px;height:400px">
<div class="easyui-draggable" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc" data-options="
            onDrag: function(e){
                constrain(e);
            },
            onStopDrag: function(e){
                constrain(e);
                $(this).css(e.data);
            }
        ">
</div>
</div>
```

Ref: http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=820.0;prev_next=prev#new

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery ui:

```
$( "#draggable").draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

If that *easyui* of yours is simply jQuery ui, which this is how it looks like, you're o.k.

[jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

Answer (score 0):

with EasyUI....

you have to make the parent div as droppable...

please view this documentation...
http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#

and here is the tutorial..
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd2.php

for example:

```
$('#yourparentDivsID').droppable({   //used ID in my case... you can use class ... or parent's selector
   onDragEnter:function(e,source){   //do your stuff here
      $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';  
   },  
   onDragLeave:function(e,source){  //do your stuff here
      $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';  
   }, 
})
```